# aws cdk appsync Schema Creation Status is FAILED with details: Internal Failure while saving the schema

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-cdk

Given the following graphql schema

```
# graphql/schema.graphql
type AppUser {
  userId: String
  fullName: String
}

type Query {
  getUser(userId: String): AppUser
  getUsers(): [AppUser]
}

type Mutation {
  addUser(user: AppUser!): AppUser
}
```

And the following cdk code defined at lib/mystack.ts:

```js
    const graphql = new appsync.GraphQLApi(this, 'GraphQLApi', {
      name: 'metrolens-graphql-api',
      logConfig: {
        fieldLogLevel: appsync.FieldLogLevel.ALL,
      },
      authorizationConfig: {
        defaultAuthorization: {
          // userPool,
          defaultAction: appsync.UserPoolDefaultAction.ALLOW,
        },
        // additionalAuthorizationModes: [{ apiKeyDesc: 'My API Key' }],
      },
      schemaDefinitionFile: props?.schemaDirectory,
    })

    const lambdaRegister = new nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'register', {
      functionName: 'register',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
      timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(10),
      entry: './lambda/register/register-0.ts',
      handler: 'handler',
      layers: [layer],
      description: 'Register a user.',
    })

    const lambdaLogin = new nodejs.NodejsFunction(this, 'login', {
      functionName: 'login',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
      timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(10),
      entry: './lambda/login/login-0.ts',
      handler: 'handler',
      layers: [layer],
      description: 'Login a user.',
    })

    const lambdaRegisterDataSource = graphql.addLambdaDataSource(
      'lambdaRegister',
      'Register lambda triggered by appsync',
      lambdaRegister
    )
    lambdaRegisterDataSource.createResolver({
      typeName: 'Mutation',
      fieldName: 'addUser',
      requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.lambdaRequest(),
      responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.lambdaResult(),
    })

    const lambdaLoginDataSource = graphql.addLambdaDataSource(
      'lambdaLogin',
      'Login lambda triggered by appsync',
      lambdaLogin
    )

    lambdaLoginDataSource.createResolver({
      typeName: 'Query',
      fieldName: 'getUsers',
      requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.lambdaRequest(),
      responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.lambdaResult(),
    })
```

I get the following error message during the `AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema` deployment phase:

GraphQLApi/Schema (GraphQLApiSchema5937B126) Schema Creation Status is FAILED with details: Internal Failure while saving the schema.

Has anyone encountered this error before? I suspect there is something wrong with my graphql schema but I couldn't tell what it was. Another answer mentioned that the DynamoDB reserved words at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html could cause conflicts, even if you don't use DynamoDB, so I renamed the `User` type to `AppSync`. However, it looks like `Query` is also a reserved word, but as far as I understand, that is also necessary for a graphql definition. Please help. AWS CDK suck hard.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The issue was my schema was incorrect. `AppUser` is a type, but I used as an input for the `addUser` mutation. You define the inputs for queries and mutations with the special `input` keyword. I ended up duplicating `AppUser` to be:

```
input AppUserInput {
  userId: String
  fullName: String
}
```

And that solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot. That error was not really descriptive.

Comment: Adding a note - use the AppSync schema editor in the console - I had the same error - turns out AppSync doesn't recognize triple quote comments which most validators allow.

Comment: I was searching the docs and you can see in the generated schema how  the inputs were used in the functions: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli-legacy/graphql-transformer/model/#generates

Answer (score 2):

Update `getUsers(): [AppUser]` to `getUsers: [AppUser]`

I came across this same error and found what it was by plugging my schema into a validator.

Entering your one gives

```
{
  "error": "Syntax error while parsing GraphQL query. Invalid input \"{\\n  getUser(userId: String): AppUser\\n  getUsers()\", expected ImplementsInterfaces, Directives, FieldDefinition or Comments (line 6, column 12):\ntype Query {\n           ^"
}
```

Comment: Which validator did you use? (and where is it located?). If possible could you please tell us the commands that you used to get that output?

Answer (score 2):

To understand where the issue appears with your graphql schema in this case, you can just go to your **AppSync API** and manually try to **add the schema** (copy/paste) and it will automatically throw an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had accidently edited the graphql from

```
enum Status { PENDING APPROVED }
```

to

```
enum String { PENDING APPROVED }
```

Reverting this change solved the issue.